# Can I change an existing auto-increment column to plain int (no-increment) and then back again after adding records

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has its primary key set to autoincrement. This table needs to be brought up to date via an import of data, but I want to assign the primary key based on the imported data not on the next incremented value. Also the data to import may not be in sequence - some ids might be missing (101,105,122 etc).

In my head I see it as
Table is at id 50 with auto increment on
Alter existing table modify primary key to straight int (no increment)
Process data.. (adding records according to imported ids 101,105,122)
Alter table when done to enable auto increment again new record should be 123

Possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert into an AUTO_INCREMENT column just as you would insert into any other column.

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, name) VALUES (101, 'Foo')
```

You can set the auto-increment to a specific value manually using an ALTER statement:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT = 123;
```

---

There is more information about this in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> To change the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT counter to be used for new rows, do this:
>
> ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
>
> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum plus one. For InnoDB, if the value is less than the current maximum value in the column, no error occurs and the current sequence value is not changed.